# How to XOR pairwise element in the same list

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a list that is always binary. I want to XOR every two consequentive elements to satisfy a condition in a research paper. For instance: Given `list=[1,0,1,1]`, XORing each consequtive pairs should be something like this: `1 XOR 0 = 1`, `0 XOR 1 = 1`, `1 XOR 1 = 0`. To do so, is it correct to XOR two lists where the second list is the shifted verison of the original Something like: `numpy.bitwise_xor([1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1])`?

Comment: wouldn't you get 3 elements as a result for pairwise XOR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the input list as an array (called a) and use [numpy.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to shift the array so that you now have another array (called b) which has stores the shifted array. Now bitwise_xor can be used on a,b.

```
 import numpy as np
 a = np.array([1,0,1,1])
 b= np.roll(a,len(a)-1)
 c = np.bitwise_xor(a,b)
 print(' A :',a,'\n','B :',b,'\n','C :',c)
```

Output:

```
 A : [1 0 1 1] 
 B : [0 1 1 1] 
 C : [1 1 0 0]
```

If you're using python 2.7, make sure the change the print statement!

Comment: Thank you very much. Good idea

Answer (score 0):

You can also use slices

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1, 0, 1, 1]
>>> print np.bitwise_xor(a[1:], a[:-1])
array([1, 1, 0], dtype=int32)
```